# Why do numeric keys in javascript always sort to the beginning?

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, properties

So let's say I have something like the following in javascript:

```
object = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "123": 123};
```

When I iterate through this, it turns out that the "123" member has jumped to the front of the list, while the order of the others is maintained.  If I do something like the following though,

```
object = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "123 STRING": 123};
```

the order is maintained. So it seems like a purely numeric key is bumped up, but a key containing non-numeric characters is not.  Anyone know why?

Comment: If you need order, use arrays. It's the only way to truly preserve order without some related "order" lookup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In V8 the data-structures behind an object vary a lot:

- In-object named properties, stored directly "on the C struct"
- Out-of-object named properties, stored in an array external to the object, additional indirection
- Indexed properties (properties whose property names can be turned into integers), stored in an array external to the object
  but the array index acts as the key
- Ordered hash table

Named properties are in insertion order because that's most natural with the hidden class evolution/transitions.

Indexed properties are in their actual value order because it would be a waste of memory to store the insertion order.

If you are backed by a hash table, the hash table deliberately fakes the same order that results from the natural
optimizations.

It is the same in other browsers too because storing indexed properties, when the numbers are small,
in an actual "C array" is a huge optimization. What can vary is whether indexed properties are listed first or named properties.

The spec made this optimization possible [by not defining iteration order](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164) and V8 was first (at least according to that bug thread) to exploit it.

Indexed keys being listed before named and vice versa is of course arbitrary and doesn't affect any optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the keys in an object is not specified in the ECMAScript standard. In other words, you have no guarantee whatsoever, the keys can be in any order.

You might one to check this post: [How to keep an Javascript object/array ordered while also maintaining key lookups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773950/how-to-keep-an-javascript-object-array-ordered-while-also-maintaining-key-lookup)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but it could be because when iterating through the keys there is no implicit order and so what you are experiencing *seems* to be strange but it's just a side-effect of probably the hash function used for the keys.

The implementation of the property bag in Javascript probably uses some tree-like data structure where keys are stored using a hash function.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we loop over an object,we mostly use `for in`

> **Iteration in for in is arbitary**

.If order is important,then you must prefer arrays.For different browsers,the order is different.

Refer the following link:
[Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop)