# How to keep order from json.parse?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object like this:
`{ "01":"111","02":"222","11":"AAA","12":"BBB"}`. But after JSON.parse, the object changed its order like `{"11":"AAA","12":"BBB","01":"111","02":"222"}`. See http://jsfiddle.net/stxh/3WV8Y/

Code:

```
var str=JSON.parse('{"01":"111","02":"222","11":"AAA","12":"BBB"}');
alert( JSON.stringify(str) );
```

Can I keep the order from JSON.parse?

Comment: This isn't a JSON problem, but a "problem" with Javascript objects: [How to keep an Javascript object/array ordered while also maintaining key lookups?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773950/how-to-keep-an-javascript-object-array-ordered-while-also-maintaining-key-lookup)

Comment: @RGraham Which is consequentially a JSON problem (as JSON explicitly *does not imply order* of keys in a JSON Object).

Comment: tldr; if you need arbitrary order, use a JSON Array. If you just want to order by key value, then order and iterate by key value.

Comment: @user2864740 Heh, depends which way you look at it I suppose!

Comment: @RGraham True, I like to push the issue as I've seen some undefined behavior (in code that later breaks) based on assumptions of JSON/dictionary ordering :(